# PHP how to combine to array values

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a list of 2 arrays,

```
 [ "4", "4"] - array of product id .
 [ "1", "2"] - array of qty.
```

if the qty is "2" in qty_array, i just want to merge the array_product like as ["4","4","4"] like way if qty is 3 i want to append like ["4","4","4","4"]
kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_fill()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php), then merge them in. This is presuming both `$qty` and `$products` are both the same length.

```
<?php
$products = [ "4", "5", "8"];
$qty = ["1", "3", "4"];

$result = [];
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    $result = array_merge(array_fill(0, $qty[$key], $product), $result);
}

print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 4
)
```

https://3v4l.org/Rd4iR

Could also use a for loop:

```
<?php
$products = ["4", "5", "8"];
$qty = ["1", "3", "4"];

$result = [];
foreach ($qty as $key => $q) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $q; $i++) {
        $result[] = $products[$key];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: wow, that's really great thank you, @Lawrence Cherone. but in this line ,u mentioned 0  is not understanding-> $result = array_merge(array_fill(0, $qty[$key], $product), $result);

Comment: Its the start index of the array, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php